# Dark energy/dark matter erodes confidence in origin theories

Tags: big-bang, dark-matter, dark-energy

My layman's understanding is that we believe we have a good understanding of the development of the universe after the instant of the Big Bang.

Also, I understand that we believe that about 95% of the universe is composed of dark energy/dark matter and that we do not understand what those really are.

So, how can we have any confidence in theories about the origin/development of the whole universe when we admittedly don't understand the composition of the vast majority of the universe?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please note that the Big Bang is a model and not a theory. The difference is possibly the key to an answer.